# Microsoft reporting rdlc performance issues exporting to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, rdlc

I'm using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms to generate pdf files but it is taking too long to create even a simple file, so far I tried to create a simple report with a parameter 'Name' and a textbox to render it, just that and it takes about 4 secs, any help on the subject would be appreciated, this is the sample code:

```cs
public byte[] GenerateReport(string name)
{
   var report = new LocalReport();
   var deviceInfo = string.Format(@"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>{0}</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>", "pdf");
   report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "namespace.TestReport.rdlc"
   report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Name", name));
   return report.Render("pdf", deviceInfo);
}
```

and it takes about 4 secs to run just that, I have a slightly more complex report and it takes a little more than 6 seconds,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that not this code but rather your reportserver and database setup, network, cpu and memory load as well as you database schema, tables, indexes etc play a role in the performance. Based on this little piece of code there is no way an answer could be usefull. You might want to use sql profiler to see if that shows anything that slows down your queries.

Comment: thanks for your response but for the example I'm using Dtos generated in memory, so no SQL, DB whatsoever involved, seems to me like library performance issue on Microsoft reporting  again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try these...

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence);
reportViewer.LocalReport.AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain("Contoso.Utilities, 
      Version=1.0.271.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89012dab8080cc90");
```

as provided in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.executereportincurrentappdomain(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: sorry the after a long time testing this i realized it only happened when running a NUnit test, it works just fine otherwise, should anyone know why, I'd really like to know